# How to delete aui.css from pages in Liferay 7

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

How to disable aui.css for custom pages in Liferay 7. Is it possible to do this somehow via portal-notmal.ftl

Answer (score 0):

aui.css is coming in through the [unstyled theme](https://github.com/liferay/com-liferay-frontend-theme/tree/7.0.x/frontend-theme-unstyled/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/_unstyled/css), which typically is the basis for every theme there is. That being said, you can override it and remove it this way. It's refined in the [styled theme](https://github.com/liferay/com-liferay-frontend-theme/tree/7.0.x/frontend-theme-styled/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/_styled/css), and also in the classic theme (in the same github repo, you'll find it).

If you do so, note that you'll still have to deal with a lot of formatting on your own - the classes and other DOM elements will be generated, but it looks like aui now includes the Lexicon CSS that you'll have to simulate if you get rid of it. Why you'd want to do so, instead of accepting the defaults and overriding what you don't like, is beyond me.

Edit, answering to your comment:

You'd simply [create your own theme](https://dev.liferay.com/en/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-1/creating-themes) (Linking to 7.1 here, see below) with any overrides that you'd like to have. There's not a single file with an option, as this configuration file would be too complex and unmanageable.

Also, you sound like you've just started building your site - my recommendation would be to always go with the latest release and use 7.1 (at this time) and note that 7.2 is around the corner, Beta 3 has just been released

Comment: I downloaded the Liferay Wild Fly bundle from the official site, is there a configuration file in it or something like that, where I can customize the styles

Comment: Perhaps there is an opportunity to make changes to top_head_include and remove this style from there?

Comment: You can make a lot of changes to a lot of files everywhere. However, with an update, e.g. when you want to install a bugfix version, you'll curse at Liferay for being hard to maintain. I'm assuming that you'll create your own theme anyway - to make your site look like it's yours. Use that opportunity and tune the theme so that it does whatever you need. And if you edit random files, don't come back complaining that a Liferay installation with random edits is hard to maintain (because it is). There are standard extension points, and proper modules that you can write. Do your future self a favor

Comment: Speaking of maintainability: Reading this again, I like my answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55871855/replacing-top-head-jsp-liferay-with-a-custom-one), as a rather general statement, better than this one. IMHO both questions could be answered almost the same way.