# Replacing top-head.jsp Liferay with a custom one

Tags: liferay-7

In portal-normal.ftl I use top-head.jsp is it possible to replace it and use the custom page?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. In general, you can customize *everything* in Liferay.

However, this and [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55869178/how-to-delete-aui-css-from-pages-in-liferay-7) make me believe that you are going for the wrong solution to whatever problem you have. If you look at top_head.jsp, there is a lot of functionality made available on every page. Unless you're prepared to lose it all, you'll have to replace it with your own implementation.

In order to add something to top_head.jsp, you should use one of the two offered [dynamic includes](https://dev.liferay.com/en/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-1/dynamic-includes).

While a simple "yes" fully answers your question, it might be more productive to let us know about the underlying problem that you're intending to solve with this technique. I bet that there's a better solution for it, and especially one that is a lot easier to maintain.